# Convert JavaScript date() to Python Django models.DateTimeField

Tags: javascript, python, django, datetime

I using django model forms to submit data to the database.
I use JavaScript to auto-fill the form with the following

```
document.getElementById('id_date_received').value = Date();
```

This outputs: **`Mon Feb 06 2017 11:39:05 GMT+0000 (GMT)`**
while django's **models.DateTimeField** expects: **`2017-02-06 11:39`**

How do i convert: **`Mon Feb 06 2017 11:39:05 GMT+0000 (GMT)`** to **`2017-02-06 11:39`**
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), it's the easiest javascript library to manipulate dates and timezone formats.

So the code would by something like this:

```
moment(YOUR_DATE_VARIABLE).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'); // 2017-02-06 11:39
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 10):

IMO, the best solution would be using **unix timestamps**, because you can avoid all complex stuff connected with timezones and time parsing.

**JS:**

```
js_date = new Date('2012.08.10');

// getTime() returns milliseconds from the UNIX epoch,
// so divide it by 1000 to get the seconds representation.

js_timestamp = js_date.getTime() / 1000;
```

**Python:**

```
python_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(js_timestamp)
```

Comment: this is the best answer IMHO, because it is server agnostic.

Comment: @Alex T How about if I want to save datetime objects in django in the above JavaScript default format. It is more classic.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the pattern of date in your  model form that accept particular format.

```
input_formats=[list of datetime patterns that you want to accept]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a long-winded solution but this should work to convert Date to django date time

I first convert the Date to a string by cast

```
(String(date_var))
```

then when I receive the API call I convert it using this command

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(",".join(original_time[:original_time.find("(")-1].split(" ")).replace("GMT",""), '%a,%B,%d,%Y,%H:%M:%S,%z')
```

I would recommend preserving the timezone as different servers can be in different timezones which can screw up your dates!

Comment: I realized that this answer is EST specific, so what you need to do first is get rid of everything past the first "(" and then you can do away with the [:-3] in my answer